# Is there a way to truncate an open filestream?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, fstream

I am opening a file in both read and write mode. I am reading file contents and want to clear the file contents after reading it but before closing the stream. I tried searching on Google but can't find any info.

Note: I don't want to truncate file while opening it.

If its not possible using standard C++ is it possible using any other library like boost or Qt?

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++ has no support for this, but the usual operating systems do: `truncate` under Posix, and `SetEndOfFile` under Windows.

Comment: This requires to get the HANDLE. How can I get the handle of a file opened with fstream?

Comment: @user221458 You can't (unless Microsoft has an extension, like most Unix do).  You have to determine the position (for this use, the return value of `tellg` or `tellg` should work, at least with the Microsoft implementation), then close the file, then open it with `CreateFile` to get the handle (and then close it after the `SetEndOfFile`).

Comment: I don't want to close the file. That's the issue. I want to do that while the file is open for a security reason. And I don't think I can use CreateFile while the fstream is already open.

Comment: @user221458 It depends on how you've opened the file.  Of course, since the open was actually in the `filebuf`, you have no real control over it.  Maybe you should just write your own `streambuf` which does what you want, and supports the additional operations.